# I cannot close terminal after updating my pc

Tags: upgrade, command-line

I am a complete novice with Ubuntu. I have installed 12.04 and just run update from terminal.

Now cannot exit terminal which appears every time I open my USer Account. I can use `exit` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to close the window but it just loops back to my password screen and once entered just goes back to screen with terminal open - showing `computername/user Jq:~$` then cursor.

Looked for help on previous questions but am really out of my depth (drowning)I have tried <kbd>TAB</kbd>-><kbd>ENTER</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-><kbd>Shift</kbd>-><kbd>W</kbd> &(<kbd>Q</kbd>), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, `jobs`, `bg` and `fg` without any effect.

Can still operate under another user account but my "primary" account is in loop.

Has my update effort done something wrong? Would really appreciate any assistance.

THanks for help. The Terminal is on a black screen, sometimes full page and randomly a smaller box bu always with nothing else. I hope this is the correct way to answer queries.

Comment: Can you add more informations? For example what DE are you using? Is the same of other users? And try to check log in /var/log/Xorg.0.log for errors and add them to your question.

Comment: is this a terminal is a window, where you still have the unity launcher and top menu, or is it full-screen with nothing else?

Answer (score 0):

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type: `xkill`
2. Click on terminal window.